# Is there a realtime linear phase EQ available for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, core-audio, equalizer

I think Core Audio has an EQ audio unit but wasn't very lucky finding good information on it. Is this a linear phase EQ? How many bands / channels does it support?

Are there open source libraries which provide a realtime linear phase EQ for iOS?

Answer (score 3):

I am almost positive the built-in stuff is IIR (minimum phase).

I'm not aware of any opensource FIR (linear phase) filters that are high quality and correctly implemented. As a starting point, Sox says it has an [FIR filter as a work in progress](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features). Audacity may have some simple FIR filters as well.

Comment: What is the difference between FIR and IIR anyways? I just heard linear phase EQ is better. But why?

Comment: I will try to answer you about the difference. As to which is better, that is somewhat hotly debated. I'll just say that here are the two most expensive digital audio EQs I know of. One is IIR and the other is both IIR and FIR:http://www.z-sys.com/pp_6ch.html http://www.weiss.ch/eq1/eq1.html

Comment: I wrote a blog post about the difference, since it's too long to answer here. It's not the best written thing ever, but I hope it will make sense to you: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/11/audio-iir-v-fir-eqs.html